# how to change the value of a variable inside an if loop each time the if loop is triggered ?

Tags: python, loops

i am trying to use codeacademy to learn python. the assignment is to "Write a function called fizz_count that takes a list x as input and returns the count of the string “fizz” in that list."

```
# Write your function below!
 def fizz_count(input):
     x = [input]
     count = 0
     if x =="fizz":
         count = count + 1
         return count
```

i think the code above the if loop is fine since the error message ("Your function fails on fizz_count([u'fizz', 0, 0]); it returns None when it should return 1.") only appears when i add that code.

i also tried to make a new variable (new_count) and set that to count + 1 but that gives me the same error message

I would appreciate your assistance very much

Comment: `input` is already a list. You do not need to nest it inside another list literal.

Comment: By the sounds of it, you're just after `return input.count('fizz')` - you don't need to retain a counter around in your fizz_count function. At the moment your function is always going to fall off the end of the function and return `None`...

Comment: jon clements, that worked :D 
do you want to post that as an answer ? so i can upvote and set as solution ?

Comment: @Jon: Although `input.count` does the work for you, it would be more pedagogical to implement it oneself.  @user1476390: your implementation needs a `for` loop, at the very least.  Oops, now there's lots of answers that give the whole thing away...

Comment: I'm sorry, an `if` statement is a loop now?

Comment: i thought that saying if ____ something___something___, that is a if loop ? 
Please correct me if i am wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have no loop.

```
# Write your function below!
 def fizz_count(input):
     count = 0
     for x in input: # you need to iterate through the input list
         if x =="fizz":
             count = count + 1
     return count
```

There is a more concise way by using the `.count()` function:

```
def fizz_count(input):
    return input.count("fizz")
```

Comment: would x become a list in the for loop ?
I am confused because the instructions said to make a list x as input.

Comment: `x` takes on the value of each element in the list `input`.  In this case, in the first loop iteration, `x` becomes the first element in the list.  In the second loop iteration, `x` becomes the second element in the list, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of `x = [input]`, that just creates another list containing the list `input`.

> *i think the code above the if loop is fine*

[`if`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements)s don't loop; you're probably looking for [`for`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements):

```
for x in input:  # 'x' will get assigned to each element of 'input'
    ...
```

Within this loop, you would check if `x` is equal to `"fizz"` and increment the count accordingly (as you are doing with your `if`-statement currently).

Lastly, move your `return`-statement out of the loop / if-statement. You want that to get executed after the loop, since you always want to traverse the list *entirely* before returning.

As a side note, you shouldn't use the name `input`, as that's already assigned to a [built-in function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input).

Putting it all together:

```
def fizz_count(l):

    count = 0  # set our initial count to 0

    for x in l:  # for each element x of the list l
        if x == "fizz":  # check if x equals "fizz"
            count = count + 1  # if so, increment count

    return count  # return how many "fizz"s we counted
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def fizz_count(x):                       #DEFine func
    count = 0                            #set counter to zero
    for item in x:                       
        if item == "fizz" :               
            count += 1                   #iterate counter +1 for each match
    print count                          #print result
    return count                         #return value 
fizz_count(["fizz","buzz","fizz"])       #call func
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# Write your function below!
def fizz_count(x):
    count = 0
    for item in x:
        if item == "fizz": 
            count = count + 1
    return count
```

Answer (score -2):

```
def fizz_count(input)
    count = 0
    for x in input:
        count +=  1 if x=="fizz" else 0
    return count
```

Comment: You could make this working by changing `count += x=="fizz" ? 1 : 0` to `count += (x=="fizz")`. If it is True, it is evaluated as 1, else 0. To make it more readable, however, you can change it to: `count += 1 if x=="fizz" else 0`.

Comment: I would prefer a simple `if`-statement to both of those alternatives.

Comment: Sorry guys, I'm always surprised when I rediscover that Python lacks the Ternary Operator.